# Install Intel IPP (libipps.so) in Docker image

Tags: docker, ubuntu, intel-ipp

I'm creating a Docker image to run my node.js app based on the `ubuntu:latest` image and I need Intel Performance Primitives (IPP) to be installed on it.

I've looked online as to how to do that but haven't found anything really.

Any ideas?

Comment: https://github.com/shaoguangleo/docker-centos-ipp/blob/master/Dockerfile

Comment: or you may manually take all *.so, *.a and header files from your local systems and copy all of these stuff to your docker.